# Query Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to filter out all Names that do not match in my data base using `Same?:StrComp(Str1, Str2).` When I run the the field in my Query My Columns have 0's for matching and 1,-1, even #ERROR because one side of the compare is empty.

```
Same?   Our DataBase Name   Other DataBase Name      ID
0      Aaron B                    AARON B          00002
1      Aaron P.                   AARON J M P      00003
#Error Ainsley W                  #Error           00004
```

So I tried in the Criteria section in design view  `Not = 0`  to get all entries that are not the same, but I get the error message Data Type Mismatch. I then tried`Iff(StrComp(Str1, Str2)=0,"Yes","No")` then in the Criteria section `"No"` Same error came up.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason it works using `Iff(StrComp(Str1, Str2)=0,"Yes","No")`
then in the criteria `Like "No*"` then it filters all the No's also I had to filter out the #Error message in another query so those do not show up.